# Which calendars does JodaTime support?

Tags: java, jodatime

Today i read about Joda time And they tells **"Calendar support. The library currently provides 8 calendar systems. More will be added in the future."**

I dont know what is 8 calender systems and also dont know how many systems are currently used ?

Give me some Specifications...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The calendar systems are the ones shown in the [`org.joda.time.chrono`](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/api-release/org/joda/time/chrono/package-frame.html) package:

- [Gregorian](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/api-release/org/joda/time/chrono/GregorianChronology.html)
- [Julian](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/api-release/org/joda/time/chrono/JulianChronology.html)
- [Buddhist](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/api-release/org/joda/time/chrono/BuddhistChronology.html)
- [Coptic](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/api-release/org/joda/time/chrono/CopticChronology.html)
- [Ethiopic](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/api-release/org/joda/time/chrono/EthiopicChronology.html)
- [Gregorian/Julian](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/api-release/org/joda/time/chrono/GJChronology.html) (with a cutover)
- [Islamic](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/api-release/org/joda/time/chrono/IslamicChronology.html)
- [ISO](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/api-release/org/joda/time/chrono/ISOChronology.html) (almost identical to Gregorian)

I'm not sure what you mean by "how many systems are currently used"

Comment: Thnx I dont know We can use all in java 7 ?

Comment: @Samir: If you're using Joda Time, yes. Obviously you can't use those classes if you're not using Joda Time...

Comment: But java have date and calender so why its need and its has some other Features can you give me some help or tuts to clear this concepts...

Comment: @Samir: Joda Time is a *far* superior API to `Date`/`Calendar` in any number of ways. The calendar system is only one aspect of Joda Time. I'm sure if you look you can find lots of documentation giving examples of how it's superior.

Answer (score 1):

On the top  of that page you maybe you [read](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/):

> Joda-Time provides a quality replacement for the Java date and time classes. The design allows for multiple [calendar systems](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_calendars),
>   while still providing a simple API. The 'default' calendar is the
>   ISO8601 standard which is used by XML. The Gregorian, Julian,
>   Buddhist, Coptic, Ethiopic and Islamic systems are also included, and
>   we welcome further additions. Supporting classes include time zone,
>   duration, format and parsing.